# SQL Sum Calculation Confusion

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new with mysql and working to change a store application to make it have two stock. I created a table to store stock quantity:

[image]

Then I plan to create a view with stock quantity, per store, per SKU. I using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `stockList`.`sku`, 
    SUM(A.`stockQty`) AS 'store1', 
    SUM(B.`stockQty`) AS 'store2', 
    SUM(`stockList`.`stockQty`) AS 'total' 
FROM `stockList` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM `stockList` WHERE `idStock`=1
) AS A 
ON `stockList`.`sku`=A.`sku` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM `stockList` WHERE `idStock`=2
) AS B 
ON `stockList`.`sku`=B.`sku` 
GROUP BY `stockList`.`sku`
```

Per resulting table, calculation is not proper and I could not identify the logic:

[image]

SKU 43 should show for store1 = 9 and for store2 = 10, total = 19. This is what they show if I execute the select queries alone. Please, let me know if I misunderstood how this sum logic works.

Comment: What does idStock and sku mean?

Comment: idStock -> integer identification for each stock, defined in another table;

Comment: sku -> Stock Keeping Unit, used to be unique identification for each single product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might to use `SUM` on subquery to calculate Totle price by `sku`

`LEFT JOIN` may make some fields not match causing `NULL` so use IFNULL to preset value `0`

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
      T.sku,
      SUM(T.stockQty) as totle,
      IFNULL(A.`store1`,0) AS `store1`,
      IFNULL(B.`store2`,0) AS `store2`
FROM `stockList` AS T
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT sku,SUM(`stockQty`) as `store1`
    FROM `stockList` 
    WHERE `idStock`=1
    GROUP BY sku
) as A ON A.sku = T.sku
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT sku,SUM(`stockQty`) as `store2`
    FROM `stockList` 
    WHERE `idStock`=2
    GROUP BY sku
) AS B ON  T.sku =B.sku
GROUP BY T.sku
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/568102/11)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is much more complicated than it needs to be. You can just do this:

```
SELECT 
  sku,
  SUM(stockQty) as total,
  SUM(IF(idStock=1,stockQty,0)) AS `store1`,
  SUM(IF(idStock=2,stockQty,0)) AS `store2`
FROM `stockList`
GROUP BY sku
```

Output:

```
sku     total   store1  store2
36      10      10      0
37      3       3       0
38      4       4       0
39      3       3       0
40      10      10      0
41      12      12      0
42      12      12      0
43      19      9       10
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. This is realy more elegant way to do it!